# Are there any implementations of bayesian optimization with mutual information as acquisition function?

Tags: mutual-information, bayesian-optimization

I'm looking for packages of **bayesian optimization with mutual information** as acquisition function.

There are many implementations of bayesian optimization in some programming languages like python, R, etc. But UCB, PI or EI are used as acquisition function in these implementation. I'm looking for packages of **bayesian optimization with mutual information** as acquisition function.

Are there any packages of bayesian optimization with mutual information as acquisition function?

Comment: Do you have a reference for mutual information as an acquisition function? This is a new one for me, and I'd like to read about it.

Comment: @Sycorax [This paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/contal14.pdf) may be the first appearance of using mutual information as an acquisition function. This paper was published in 2014 and is very new.

Comment: Have you inquired with the authors of the paper?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone No, I haven't yet, I'll ask! I don't have that idea. Thanks!!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I received a reply from one of the authors of the paper and my question was solved. Therefore I answered my own question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BayesOpt](https://github.com/rmcantin/bayesopt) in order to use **bayesian optimization with mutual information** as an acquisition function in your program.

> BayesOpt is an efficient implementation of the Bayesian
>   optimization methodology for nonlinear optimization, experimental
>   design and hyperparameter tunning.

This library has [bayesopt::MutualInformation Class](https://rmcantin.bitbucket.io/html/classbayesopt_1_1MutualInformation.html) as a criteria function.
This one is just what you wanted.